# Issue with Array formula entered into cells by VBA is not behaving as expected

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having issues with using VBA to insert an array formula into a column and copy downwards for as many rows that have data in the worksheet that the formula is referencing.

If I use CSE and then afterwards drag down, the formula works as expected.
I then used the macro recorder to capture the CSE and to convert the formula to VBA and this is where it fails.

I have tried as many variations on entering the formula as I can find but nothing works.

The array formula which is entered into **cell C2** in a worksheet called "**Pack**" looks at **Cell A1** of a worksheet called "**FolderDataImport**" and if data is present it then performs a couple of tasks.

This VBA that enters this formula should copy it down **Column C** as long as the corisponding cell in worksheet called "**Pack**" for as long as there is data present.

So what happens when I run the code with the array formula is that it does not auto change the cell references (as if you were dragging the formula down the column A1, A2, and so on) and just copied the same cell reference all of the way down the column.

It also changes the Cell reference from FolderDataImport!**A1** to FolderDataImport!**A1048571**?

```
Sub InsertFormulasPack()
    Dim SWs As Worksheet, TWs As Worksheet
    Dim Lr As Long
    `...
    Set SWs = Worksheets("FolderDataImport")
    Set TWs = Worksheets("Pack")
    Lr = SWs.Range("A" & SWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    `...
 
    ' Column C Formula
        TWs.Range("C2:C" & Lr + 1).FormulaArray = _
        "=MID(FolderDataImport!R[-7]C[-2],FIND(""-"",FolderDataImport!R[-7]C[-2])+2,MIN(FIND({""["",""(""},FolderDataImport!R[-7]C[-2]))-FIND(""-"",FolderDataImport!R[-7]C[-2])-3)"
    
    '...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

An Array Formula can take two forms:

- If you select a range, the enter a formula with CSE, it will be a single array formula applying to the selected range. (This is what your VBA code is trying to do)
- If you select a single cell, enter a formula with CSE, then drag down, each cell will contain a seperate array formula (This is what you seem to want to achieve)

To achieve the second option, this technique can be used

```vb
With TWs.Range("C2:C" & Lr + 1)
    'create a standard formula
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(FolderDataImport!R[-1]C[-2],FIND(""-"",FolderDataImport!R[-1]C[-2])+2,MIN(FIND({""["",""(""},FolderDataImport!R[-1]C[-2]))-FIND(""-"",FolderDataImport!R[-1]C[-2])-3)"
    
    'convert to array formula
    .FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1
End With
```

Note:

1. there is an issue in your code, you using `R[-7]C[-2]` in cell `C2`.  Row 2 - 7 wraps to the end of the sheet, thus refers to row 1048571.  I used `R[-1]C-2]` in my demo, you'll have to adjust it to get the offset you actually want.
2. Without sample data I can't be sure this gives the correct formula, but it does demonstarte how to enter array formulas

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your suggestions but I was seeking a solution that did not involve a seperate sub. Also with regard to the so called "wall of code" I included it so that viewers may see what it does. I am damned if  do and damned if I dont.

Here is the answer to my issue.
TWs.Range("C2").FormulaArray = "=MID(FolderDataImport!A1,FIND(""-"",FolderDataImport!A1)+2,MIN(FIND({""["",""(""},FolderDataImport!A1))-FIND(""-"",FolderDataImport!A1)-3)"

TWs.Range("C2").Copy TWs.Range("C3:C" & Lr + 1)

This is entered in the existin sub at the heading Column C Formula.

This may help others who need a solution like this.